# Certutil intended purposes

Tags: certutil

On some systems where we're deploying our software, we're told that it is missing a certificate that necessary to verify our code is correctly signed.
I'd like to add this certificate in our (nsis) installer.

I'm using the following command: 
`nsExec::Exec 'certutil -addstore "Root" "$INSTDIR\root.cer"'`

It works fine, except it gets installed with "intended purposes" set to all.
Rather I would like to have them like this:

[image: DigiCert properties]

Any suggestions on about how to proceed?

Addendum: double clicking the .cer file, Key Usage lists the following:

[image]

Comment: Does the certificate include a statement of its purpose? If not, add it to the cert and try whenever it will be detected properly afterwards.

Comment: How ? I've exported it from certIm (microsoft management console) and did not have the option to select these properties. Also a certificate downloaded from Digicert was same result. I have no idea if the .cer file contains the necessary properties and if or how they can be added.

Comment: The [properties such as intended uses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_policy#Certificate_uses) of certificates are decided on creation. If you do have the `.cer` you can check it using the regular properties dialog. It does have an intended purposes field. If it is issue by digicert that should be a given though. It doesn't look like you will be able to modify the options you want. Also note the "Note" above the selection.

Comment: Not a way to see in "properties" but double clicking does open a dialog, I've added it the question... can't find the "properties" you mean...

Comment: You actually selected what I meant. Those key usage parameters are usually what should determine how a certificate is used. Looking at what you currently got, are you sure you want to change that? The certificate you got is meant to be used to sign other certificates. For instance you'd use it to sign a certificate for a particular software you wrote, instead of changing the intended purposes of that certificate. DId you check whenever editing the intended purposes actually works? As it is I wonder whenever it should fail according to the warning above.

Comment: Yes, modifying these certificate properties works. And the problem is that such exported certificate when imported with certutil sets the certificate to be set to ALL purposes, which is too permissive...